# how we send data using function in the form of array as parameter and perform OR operation in sql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to send OR operation date in codeigniter using function:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Queries');
    $posts = $this->Queries->get(['title' => 'Mansh'OR'id' => 1],'*',2);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($posts);
    echo "</pre>";
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Comment: You means you want build query with or like title = 'Mansh' OR id=1 right?

Comment: your controller gets the two variables. then you call a model function and pass the two variables, for each variable not blank then you add a where clause with that variable.